# Can I log in into an application with Selenium and then get the bearer token generated and use it in the API call?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-devtools, rest-assured, bearer-token

Can you log in to an application with Selenium and then get the bearer token of that session for using it into API call? Is there a way to get bearer token?

I can not log in to the application with the login API as the password is salted... And for performing operations after login using API call, I need the bearer token, so can you get the bearer token?

Or else can we use the login API with a salted password generator, but the salted password functionality is not known!

I have tried using jsexecuter for getting the bearer token.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would look into [JMeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JMeter) and making the API calls through that.

You can parameterize JMeter calls and extract values from responses on JMeter to use on the next call...

Have a look at that.

Selenium doesn't do what you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/). Below is the example code.

```java
public String accessToken = "";

@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void getAPITokenFromBrowser() {
    Playwright playwright = Playwright.create();
    Browser browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions().setHeadless(false));
    Page page = browser.newPage();

    page.onRequest(request -> {
        if (request.url().equals("www.YOUR_APP_URL" + "/API_PATH_FROM_NETWORK_TAB")) { //if the API Call is found with above condition then spliting using Space because these days api tokens are in format "Bearer abcdsdsdsd"

            String[] token = request.headers().get("authorization").split(" ");
            this.accessToken = token[1];
            System.out.println("AccessToken: " + accessToken);
        }

    });

    page.navigate(YOUR_URL);
    page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.LOAD);
    page.fill("UsernameXpath", "username");
    page.fill("PasswordXpath", "Password");
    page.click("LoginBtnXpath");
    page.waitForLoadState(LoadState.LOAD);
    playwright.close();
}
```

Once this code block gets executed, you will have your token in the variable *accessToken*. The only important thing here is to *identify* the API_PATH_FROM_NETWORK_TAB.